# Is copy/rename a good way to improve temp table performance?

Tags: postgresql, performance, temporary-tables

An application I am working with contains this sequence of queries at the end of constructing a large temp table; I believe it is an attempt to improve performance by pruning dead tuples -

```
create temp table tmp_foo_new as select * from tmp_foo;
drop table tmp_foo;
alter table tmp_foo_new rename to tmp_foo;
```

Some rudimentary benchmarks do indicate this sequence does improve performance substantially, so it is worthwhile.  It feels somewhat hacky to me though.  Is there a more canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the table has an index, you may want to consider the [`cluster`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-cluster.html) command instead of re-creating it or using `vacuum full`. This will:

- Have the same effect on dead tuples - it physically re-writes the whole table
- Retains any existing indexes
- Might improve performance more than just removing dead tuples, depending on whether you will benefit from the clustering too (though of course you could achieve the same with an `order by` clause when re-creating)

Answer (score 1):

It achieves the same effect as a [VACUUM FULL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-vacuum.html) except that it can be executed within a transaction block. Of course, any indices or constraints on the original table would be lost in the given example.

I would need to know some additional information to help explain the performance increase:

1. Are there any indices or constraints on the original table?
2. Is there a substantial performance increase relative to performing a regular VACUUM on the table?
3. How frequently are tuples deleted or updated as part of constructing the temp table?

Comment: I think performing a regular `VACUUM` on a temp table is highly unusual :)  However, the `VACUUM FULL` on it (if it fits into the memory available) seems very fast, so that might be an option.